# Reading QR Code & BarCode in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, barcode, zxing, qr-code

I am  working  on windows phone 8 App  development..My requirement is to  scan  a  QR code &  Barcode and get  the  value  embedded  to it..

I  have  tried   a lot  with  Zxing  library..
please provide  me  with  susitable  solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally  ..I have  implemented this method..

Include  following  namespace  on  your sample

```
xmlns:jwqr="clr-namespace:JeffWilcox.Controls;assembly=JeffWilcox.Controls.QR"
```

in XAml  file..
include  the  following  control

```
<jwqr:QRCodeScanner
ScanComplete="QRCodeScanner_ScanComplete"
Error="QRCodeScanner_Error"
Width="400"
Height="400"/>
```

In  code behing..include  the event handlers.

```
private void QRCodeScanner_ScanComplete(object sender, JeffWilcox.Controls.ScanCompleteEventArgs e)
{
ApplicationTitle.Text = e.Result;
}

private void QRCodeScanner_Error(object sender, JeffWilcox.Controls.ScanFailureEventArgs e)
{
throw e.Exception;
}
```

for  complete  reference..
[click here](http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2012/01/wpqr-control/)

Answer (score 1):

Include you `ZXing.Net` library into your project.

View.xaml

```
<Grid x:Name="grdCamera">
<Rectangle x:Name="_previewRect" 
       Margin="0" 
       Height="800" 
       Width="600" 
       HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
       VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <Rectangle.Fill>
        <VideoBrush x:Name="_previewVideo">
            <VideoBrush.RelativeTransform>
                <CompositeTransform  
                x:Name="_previewTransform" CenterX=".5" CenterY=".5" />
            </VideoBrush.RelativeTransform>
        </VideoBrush>
    </Rectangle.Fill>
</Rectangle>
```

C# code

```
private readonly DispatcherTimer _timer;
private PhotoCameraLuminanceSource _luminance;
private QRCodeReader _reader;
private PhotoCamera _photoCamera;

//Constructor
public ScanPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    _timer = new DispatcherTimer();
    _timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250);
    _timer.Tick += (o, arg) => ScanPreviewBuffer();
}

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    _photoCamera = new PhotoCamera();
    _photoCamera.Initialized += OnPhotoCameraInitialized;
    _previewVideo.SetSource(_photoCamera);

    CameraButtons.ShutterKeyHalfPressed += (o, arg) => _photoCamera.Focus();

    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
}

private void OnPhotoCameraInitialized(object sender, CameraOperationCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    int width = Convert.ToInt32(_photoCamera.PreviewResolution.Width);
    int height = Convert.ToInt32(_photoCamera.PreviewResolution.Height);

    _luminance = new PhotoCameraLuminanceSource(width, height);
    _reader = new QRCodeReader();

    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
    {
        _previewTransform.Rotation = _photoCamera.Orientation;
        _timer.Start();
    });
}

private void ScanPreviewBuffer()
{
    try
    {
        _photoCamera.GetPreviewBufferY(_luminance.PreviewBufferY);
        var binarizer = new HybridBinarizer(_luminance);
        var binBitmap = new BinaryBitmap(binarizer);
        var result = _reader.decode(binBitmap);
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => MessageBox.Show(result.Text));
    }
    catch
    {
    }
}
```

Following links may helps you

http://jonas.follesoe.no/2011/07/22/qr-code-scanning-on-windows-phone-75-using-zxlib/

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/27164.windows-phone-optical-reader-library-for-windows-phone-8.aspx

Answer (score 0):

For example this solution.
[RadBarCode](http://www.telerik.com/products/windows-phone/overview/all-controls/barcode.aspx)
Here is the full set of features.